# Azure function code where to place in production environment

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

Currently, I have created the Azure function app in the portal and I do the development using Visual Studio.

Now as we are moving to the production environment with Azure DevOps, I have created an ARM template for the Azure function app which creates the structure of the Azure function perfectly. But I have no idea where to keep the Azure function code and how to refer to it in the ARM template.

As per the search I did, there are options to keep the code in Github and refer to it in the ARM template. Are there any other options that should be considered for a production environment that Azure suggests?

Thanks a lot for the help here.

Comment: are you using any tool to deploy automatically ? like GitHub actions, azure pipelines ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, we will be using the Azure pipelines.

Comment: no worries, you could have a look at this articile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-functions-windows?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml

Comment: if you have azure devops, you can also have your repo in azure repos if needed/easier

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple deployment [ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies) available where we can deploy our Azure Function.

[image]

You can use Azure Functions to deploy your code continuously by using source control integration. Source control integration enables a workflow in which a code update triggers deployment to Azure

Check for Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment) for Continuous Deployment

Refer to the [blog](https://cloudskills.io/blog/azure-functions-deploy) for CI/CD